# Unprotect excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Following is my C# code,where i`m trying to unlock protected sheet by passing password,but it still not unlocking the sheet, I need to add some macro to the sheet .

Code:

```
const string excelFile = @"c:\temp\VBA\test.xlsm";
var excelApplication = new ExcelInterop.Application { Visible = true };
var targetExcelFile = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(FileName:excelFile,Password:"12asQOl");
```

I can`t use "sendKeys" here,please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One piece of advice when working with VBA: start recording a macro of what you're trying to do then see the generated code.

Looks like you're trying to open a protected file, not unprotect a sheet.

I've found some old code of something like this (it's VB):

```
Dim WSheet As Worksheet
For Each WSheet In Worksheets
    If WSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        WSheet.Unprotect Password:=MyPassword
    Else
        WSheet.Protect Password:=MyPassword
    End If
Next WSheet
```

Comment: The differences between VB 6 and C# are significant.

Comment: I didn't want to do all the work, just point him to the right direction. He was trying to open a password-protected file, when what he wanted was to unprotect a worksheet. I guess the answer and the (VB6) code made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are passing the document password. You are not un-protecting the workbook.

Use the following code to un-protect the workbook:

```
targetExcelFile.Unprotect(password);
```

Let me know if you have any issues.